# PHP quirks and pitfalls

Tags: php

I've realized that, although most of my experience consists in writing PHP applications, I find myself making "beginner mistakes" from time to time. This because PHP is a language that has grown very organically and as such has some idiosyncrasies, quirks and pitfalls that I don't know about.

I'd like this question to be a wiki for all those who want to know PHP's pitfalls and exceptions from what we might believe are the rules. But please, don't write general responses like:

> Some functions receive arguments as
>   `$needle`, `$haystack`, while some as
>   `$haystack`, `$needle`.

Tell the function names. You have a few answers from me as examples. Oh, and add one pitfall per answer. This way we'll see which is the most despised of them all (by voting).

I don't want to start a flame war, keep it to the subject. If you'd like to write some bad things about PHP then do it as a comment to the respective answer.

Hopefully this wiki will be of help for all of us, beginners and experts.

**Update:**

After Andrew Moore's comment I'm thinking that the answer should also contain a solution or workaround for the pitfall.

Comment: As from php 5.3.3 you can no longer use the class name as the constructor name if you use namespaces. You must use '__construct'. No warnings will be issued, but calling 'new MyClass' will not execute the code in your constructor. Hurray for a nice pitfall.

Answer (score 10):

Serializing objects that process XML structures and then unserializing them does not restore the original XML structure:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('<test/>');

$dom = serialize($dom);
$dom = unserialize($dom);

var_dump($dom->saveXML());
// $ Warning: DOMDocument::saveXML(): Couldn't fetch DOMDocument in ...
// $ NULL
```

Similarly for SimpleXML objects.

Answer (score 10):

I hate how you can get issues if you close php files with a `?>` closing tag (which seems like it should be the other way around). For example, include a file with some whitespace after the ?> and then try to change headers (assuming no output buffering). UGH. Took me way to long to learn to never close php files with `?>`

Answer (score 9):

Non-industry-standard operator precedence.

```
$x = 1;
echo 'foo: ' . $x+1 . ' bar';
```

Will output: "`1 bar`", instead of the expected "`foo: 2 bar`".  Solution: Use parenthesis.

Comment: echo()'s possibility to take several arguments can be used here as well: echo 'foo: ', $x+1, ' bar';

Comment: It's worth noting that there are *two* funky things about this: not only is the precedence not what you wanted, but also, ("foo: 1" + 1) doesn't concatenate; it apparently equals 1, not "foo: 11".

Comment: @ojrac, that's because the concatenation operator in PHP is . (dot), not + (plus) as in many other languages. + is used for arithmetic addition and "foo: 1" is evaluated to 0 in order to add 1 to it, thus the final result which is 1.

Answer (score 7):

Integer size is platform dependent. You can't normally use 64bit integers on a 32bit machine without any outside module. Additionally, you cannot declare unsigned integers.

Answer (score 7):

Multiple ways of doing truth tests ([not operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), [empty()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), [is_null()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php), [isset()](http://www.php.net/isset)) + weak typing = [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

With some discipline you can mostly avoid the need to refer to this table:

- For general truth tests, you can use boolean comparison `if ($)` { ... } `if (!$x) { ... }`. It behaves the way boolean operators in most languages do.
- Always use `empty()` if you want to test form input for falsy values (it treats "0" as false).
- Always use `isset()` if you want to determine whethere a variable is set or not
- Use `is_null()` or `$x === NULL` if you only need to check for NULL

Answer (score 6):

I've had all sorts of bother combining foreach with references

```
$testarray = array(1 => "one", 2 => "two");
$item = "three";
$testarray[3] =& $item;
foreach ($testarray as $key => $item) {
  // do nothing
}
echo $testarray[3]; // outputs "two"
```

This really threw me off during the PHP4 era, and although it's gotten better in PHP5 by having sane behavior if you don't use explicit references, I still manage to get caught by this one now and then.

Comment: Do you know what's going on under the hood ? I am curious why php returns this.

Comment: The =& assignment makes the final entry in the array a reference to the $item variable. On each iteration of the foreach loop that means $testarray[3] changes to be the current value of $item. Since $testarray[2] is "two", that value persists when iterating over $testarray[3], and it remains the final value of $testarray[3]

Answer (score 4):

Inconsistent naming conventions of built-in functions.  For example this set of string processing functions:

```
 str_shuffle()
 str_split()
 str_word_count()
 strcasecmp()
 strchr()
 strcmp()
```

Solution: Leave the manual open at all times.

Comment: Incidentally, part of the reason for that is that they were initially trying to emulate C with functions like `strstr()` and `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you like to pass a function-result to another function directly, which only accepts variables as input.

For example:

```
array_pop(  explode('\\', get_class($this))  )
```

…will result in an E_STRICT-error "**Only variables should be passed by reference**". To get get it working just add another pair of brackets around the inner (returned) statement:

```
array_pop( (explode('\\', get_class($this))) )
```

(If your are using namespaces and extended classes, this line returns only the class name (without namespace) from the calling object–not the parent-class which was extended and may hold this function.)

Comment: Just faced this error. Thank you for solution. By the way, additional brackets are not recognized as correct by PHPStorm. PS: This problem could also be solved using `\ReflectionObject` and `getName()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Some newly introduced PHP features fall flat because there's no guarantee they'll be supported by default in hosting environments.

The biggest peeve of mine is the `short_tags` setting that enables `<? foobar(); ?>` <s>and `<?=$var ?>`</s> tag syntax.  I argue PHP should've enabled this feature by default, rather than opt-in.

**== EDIT ==**

In PHP >= 5.4 the `short_tags` setting is no longer taken into consideration for the shorthand echo statement , as such it will be available in every hosting environment that supports PHP 5.4 and up.

Comment: I agree short tags should be the default.

Comment: short tags are evil. they mix up with XML declaration. you should not use it ...

Comment: Irrational.  The XML declaration is an edge case.  And next you're going to tell me short tags are "hard to read" and some other nonsense.  Simply put, "<?php echo" is excessive work compared to "<?=" once you've had to use it a dozen times in close proximity.  It gets to the point for me that it's easier to give up on the templating and use "echo" for all HTML rendering, like the old Perl/CGI days.

Comment: One more point, my argument is that short_tags should've been enabled by default.  The unfortunate fact that PHP went with "<?=" as the open tag is beside the point.  It's 9 characters shorter per tag than the old way.  Additionally, "ini_set()" should've allowed this setting to be overriden.  Flexibility would've been nice.

Comment: i also like short tags and also think the argument made by Philippe is sophistry.

Comment: Embedded PHP is among the worse techniques to generate XML.

Answer (score 2):

Having functions behave differently on different OS'es, and some functions are available only on specific OS'es.

For example, the `mail()` function on Windows cannot take sender name in the `$to` parameter. It can only contain email address. On Linux all works fine.

Another example, the function `strptime()` is only available on Linux, and not Windows (this got me in an existing project I wanted to run on my Windows box).

Sure, there are some functions that make sense only on certain OS'es (like Win32API functions), but many others seem like they should behave the same on all OS'es, when in fact they do not.

Comment: The `exec()` family is my favourite in this category.

Answer (score 1):

Although strings may be iterated using `for` loops and indexes, they can't be iterated using `foreach` loops. Example:

```
$str = 'foo';
$max = strlen($str);

for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++)  {
    echo $str[$i];
}
// outputs: foo

foreach ($str as $char) {
    echo $char;
}
// Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...
```

Comment: foreach(str_split($str) AS $char) { echo $char; }

Comment: This is because strings are not arrays of characters in PHP. The for loop works only because the brackets [] are syntactic sugar for accessing a particular character. Unfortunately this also gives the appearance that strings can be manipulated as arrays of characters, which as you see in the foreach loop, is untrue. As Andrew noted, using str_split() is an easy way to break it up into an actual array if that's what you need.

Comment: has nothing to do with the original post...

Comment: Dr. Hfuhruhurr, funny, because I wrote both the original post and this answer.

Answer (score 1):

my favorite:

```
<?php
$a = 0;
$b = 'x';
var_dump(FALSE == $a);
var_dump($a == $b);
var_dump($b == TRUE);

echo' <br />Conclusion: TRUE equals FALSE (at least in PHP)';
```

Comment: This can be shown in other scripting languages as well, not just PHP. It has to do with how 'x' is converted to an integer for comparison.

Comment: The == operator coerces data types.  You should be using ===, anyway.

Comment: "The == operator coerces data..." not always, Some times I do want to treat null,0,'' as false and all other as true.

Comment: @ItayMoav **Some times I do want to treat null,0,'' as false and all other as true.** - for this you should use dedicated functions is_null(), empty(), etc. Things are not done right using a type casting comparative operation, like ==, use === instead.

Comment: @Starlays :-D I am three years more experienced today...

Answer (score 1):

**== EDIT ==**
**This is no longer true for PHP >= 5.5!**

> What I sometimes run into is the `Fatal error: Can't use function
>   return value in write context` error when using the `empty()`
>   construct. For example:
>
> ```
> if (!empty(trim($_GET['s']))) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> `empty()` needs a variable, anything else will result in the error.
>
> The solution:
>
> ```
> $s = trim($_GET['s']);
> if (!empty($s)) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Simpler still: `if (!trim($_GET['s'])) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = "a string";

if ($x == 142)
{
    echo "lol, of course $x is a number";
}
else
{
    echo "$x is clearly not equal to 142";
}
```

When run:

```
lol, of course a string is a number
```

**You must use** ===

```
$x = "a string";

if ($x === 142)
{
    echo "lol, of course $x is a number";
}
else
{
    echo "$x is clearly not equal to 142";
}
```

When run:

```
a string is clearly not equal to 142
```

Comment: I believe this example, although ordinary in the PHP community, is of great help for people coming from strict programming languages. Some of them don't even know there's such thing as triple equal.

Comment: Yeah, took me a while to debug this issue in my code. I knew == coerced data types but I didn't know ("a string" == 234) would evaluate to true!!

Comment: sorry, but that is not true. "a string" == 142 will evaluate to false. see the loose comparision table on http://ch.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Philippe is right, it goes

"a string" == 142; /* false */ ... 
"a string" === 142; /* false */ ... 
"142" == 142; /* true */ ... 
"142" === 142; /* false */ ... 

Is there any version of php where ("a string" == 142) is true?